# Why can I set status color?

Tags: java, android

There is something I don't know why I have set

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LineChartActivity1"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RealtimeLineChartActivity">
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"-->

    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".Add_arg_activity"/>
</application>
```

And the RealtimeLineChartActivity's xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But!!!the screen is like this... I'm really sorry about the image, I don't have enough points in stackoverflow.

[The main activity screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCgh.png)

[The second activity screen shot(RealtimeLineChartActivity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVjNa.png)

As you can see the color in the pic, the second one is white and the first one is what i want,which has applied in

```
@style/AppTheme
```

I don't why. Please, give me something useful, I have checked lots of information.

This is the second one's activity code:

```
public class RealtimeLineChartActivity extends DemoBase implements
OnChartValueSelectedListener {

 private LineChart mChart;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_realtime_linechart);
  SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
  tintManager.setStatusBarTintResource(R.color.dark_grey);
  tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);

  mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
  mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

  // no description text
  mChart.setDescription("");
  mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

  // enable touch gestures
  mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

  // enable scaling and dragging
  mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
  mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
  mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

  // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
  mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

  // set an alternative background color
  mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

  LineData data = new LineData();
  data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  // add empty data
  mChart.setData(data);

  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

  // get the legend (only possible after setting data)
  Legend l = mChart.getLegend();

  // modify the legend ...
  // l.setPosition(LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);
  l.setForm(LegendForm.LINE);
  l.setTypeface(tf);
  l.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
  xl.setTypeface(tf);
  xl.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
  xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
  xl.setSpaceBetweenLabels(5);
  xl.setEnabled(true);

  YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
  leftAxis.setTypeface(tf);
  leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(100 f);
  leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0 f);
  leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

  YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
  rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.realtime, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.actionAdd:
    {
     addEntry();
     break;
    }
   case R.id.actionClear:
    {
     mChart.clearValues();
     Toast.makeText(this, "Chart cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     break;
    }
   case R.id.actionFeedMultiple:
    {
     feedMultiple();
     break;
    }
  }
  return true;
 }

 private int year = 2015;

 private void addEntry() {

  LineData data = mChart.getData();

  if (data != null) {

   ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
   // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

   if (set == null) {
    set = createSet();
    data.addDataSet(set);
   }

   // add a new x-value first
   data.addXValue(mMonths[data.getXValCount() % 12] + " " + (year + data.getXValCount() / 12));
   data.addEntry(new Entry((float)(Math.random() * 40) + 30 f, set.getEntryCount()), 0);


   // let the chart know it's data has changed
   mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

   // limit the number of visible entries
   mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(120);
   // mChart.setVisibleYRange(30, AxisDependency.LEFT);

   // move to the latest entry
   mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 121);

   // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
   // mChart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount()-7, 55f,
   // AxisDependency.LEFT);
  }
 }

 private LineDataSet createSet() {

  LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "Dynamic Data");
  set.setAxisDependency(AxisDependency.LEFT);
  set.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
  set.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
  set.setLineWidth(2 f);
  set.setCircleRadius(4 f);
  set.setFillAlpha(65);
  set.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
  set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
  set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  set.setValueTextSize(9 f);
  set.setDrawValues(false);
  return set;
 }

 private void feedMultiple() {

  new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
       addEntry();
      }
     });

     try {
      Thread.sleep(35);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }).start();
 }

 @Override
 public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
  Log.i("Entry selected", e.toString());
 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected() {
  Log.i("Nothing selected", "Nothing selected.");
 }
}
```

> Here is my **styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <!-- Light Indigo -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3949AB</item>
    <!-- Dark Indigo -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#00B0FF</item>
    <!-- Blue -->
    <item     name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you want to change toolbar text color and background?

Comment: first of all you dont have to write everywhere the same theme, bcz you are already set in manifest in <application> block, just remove it from the xml file.

Comment: @SagarChavada When I remove android:theme="@style/AppTheme" .It give me an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @SohailZahid I don't think so...I need a systematic knowledge for this theme in this app? Anything you need could tell me.I really need your help tks!

Comment: @SohailZahid May be you misuderstand the status bar and toolbar...

Comment: @SagarChavada Sorry,i misunderstand you.I remove it from other activity's xml.But i got the same pic like what i have above.It does not change the status bar color

Comment: ok.. just put your style.xml file here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two **styles.xml** in my project.The first is **styles.xml** the other one is **styles-v21.xml**.I did't set the item in **styles-v21.xml**.I use the android version is 6.0 API-23,So I copy the same item in **styles.xml**.It turns OK.My fault!

[The First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1NCx.png)

[The Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WgMC.png)